# How can I use Firefox under Linux on my Windows system for testing purposes?

Tags: linux, debugging, firefox, web

I have a website that is behaving differently in Windows Firefox and Linux Firefox. It has to work in both, but I don't have access to a Linux box. Is there a way to simulate running Linux Firefox for testing purposes? Thanks.

Comment: Out of interest, what is the different behaviour you're seeing between Firefox Windows and Linux? It's possible that it may not be directly related to the operating system. For example, if it's using different default fonts (because the standard Windows fonts aren't installed on the Linux box), then the layout may be affected. This isn't a Linux issue directly, because if you install the fonts it's fine, but your layout needs to be able to handle an alternate font being used. (I've seen this issue before, btw)

Comment: One of the problems is that media queries and/or calls to the window object in javascript don't seem to be working. There are other issues, but we only know the symptoms, not the cause.

Comment: Fair enough. It'll be interesting to see how that pans out, whether it really is related to the OS, or something else. Either way, yes; you definitely need to test it for yourself.  :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Virtual Machine (like Oracle VM Box) + Linux distribution + Firefox for Linux should work

Comment: Thanks, I'll check into those.

Comment: If it work, don t forget to accept the answer so future viewer know how to solve the problem, if it don t, comment

Comment: For thoses who wich to test on Debian, Firefox is the default browser, but under the name of Iceweasel

Answer (score 2):

You say you don't have a linux box, but that's easily solved.

Linux distros are free to download, free to install and use. All you need is a machine to install it onto.

You could set it up to dual-boot with your existing OS, so you don't even need dedicated hardware.

If you don't have a machine that you're willing to install it onto direct, you can still install it into a virtual machine (VM).

There's plenty of free VM software you can use; download and install that, then run up a new VM and install your preferred Linux distro onto it. Now you've got linux running in a window on your existing desktop. You can start and stop it at any time.

For what it's worth, this is also a good way of testing multiple IE versions as well; even if you have Windows OS, you can't install multiple IE versions, so use a VM for each IE version and you can test your site in any version of IE you want.